# Absolute position for color picker in html with css

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am using https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum to show a color picker.

In my index.html I have:

```
<input id="colorPicker" style="position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 20px">
```

And in my js file I write:

```
$("#colorPicker").spectrum({
    color: "#f00"
});
$("#colorPicker").parent().css({position: 'relative'});
$("#colorPicker").css({top: 200, left: 200, position:'absolute'});
```

But the color picker is still not absolute to the canvas, its just laying on the left side and pushes everything to the right.

http://jsfiddle.net/raum9ebn/33/
I want the color picker on top of the image.

Comment: Please reproduce the issue on Fiddle or add a Stack Snippet.

Comment: Are you calling these lines after the page completely loads? Please add the code in a Fiddle as @chipChocolate.py mentioned.

Comment: fiddle link is added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raum9ebn/34/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6l6v2.png" id="ballon" />    
    <input type="color" class="cp" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cp{
    position: absolute; 
    z-index:1;
    top: 15px; 
    left: 20px;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
}
```

I fixed couple of things as follows:

- Encapsulated both controls, the image and color picker into a div and assigned that div a relative position
- add z-index = 1 to the color picker

Note:
I added my own color picker which is native html5 color picker and it worked
However, your JQuery generated one did not work but I did not check why